# fix pivot joint corona lua

Tags: lua, box2d, coronasdk

I want to build a powerboat with an attached engine at the back seen from top down. 
Therefore I use a pivot joint. But after changing the rotation of the engine for steering, it would be great to fix the angle or to change the joint into a weld joint.

Is there a way to do this?

best,
Joerg

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using a pivot joint for the attached engine is really the way to go. The engine rotates directly under the player's control, not as a result of external forces. Instead of using your powerboat image as the physics object, you should create a group and insert both the powerboat and the engine into that group, and then use addBody on that group. Now you can rotate the engine at will and it'll move with the boat without it being affected by physics.